# Blank window vscode as root

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04, vscode-tasks

it's been a long time that i run vscode as root via this command (ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) :

```
> sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"
```

Today, i used the same command to execute vscode as root, but i don't have the same result.
in this time, i have a blank window.

i tried to remove it + remove /$Home/Code and .vscode folder
install it again but i have the same problem,
i tried to use the same command with other flags without being able to solve it.

```
Flags tried : --disable-gpu    ///  --disable-features=CalculateNativeWinOcclusion
```

is there a way to delete (package + config) and all data of vscode to install it properly again ?

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atIgk.png)

Any idea ?
Thank you & have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151187

keys must be used:
`--no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox --user-data-dir`

for example:
`sudo code --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox --user-data-dir=/root/.vscode/`

Comment: Finally, the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

That works for me on `VSCodium`:

```bash
sudo su -c "codium --user-data-dir="/root" --no-sandbox && sleep infinity"
```

For some reason, `vscode` does not start with `sudo`, but it works calmly with `su -c`

PS: I do not know if it can be done easier. I needed this to work with git in vscode

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing the issue to open a code that is present under /root.

then better add permission to root.

For example:

`chmod -R 755 /root/`

Now, you can easily open the root file with vscode